# Difference between contract and catch [a disease]

Tags: meaning, differences, verbs, synonyms

What could be the difference between ***contracting*** a disease and ***catching*** a disease?

I know there isn't any big difference. However, it looks like there are some diseases you can both catch and contract and others you can only either catch or contract.

Comment: As far as I know, you catch a disease from another human. In other words it is contagious. You contract a disease if comes from somewhere else such as contaminated food or an insect bite. In other words, you can catch the flu from your sibling but contract dengue from a mosquito.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While the terms are often used interchangeably with regard to illness, there are some differences.

**[Contract](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contract?q=contract)**, in this context, means

> [with object] catch or develop (a disease or infectious agent):
>   *three people contracted a killer virus*

The term is regularly used with chronic diseases:

> Women in their 30s and 40s are TWICE as likely to contract cancer than men - with breast cancer largely to blame

[*Daily Mail*](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-2349455/Women-30s-40s-TWICE-likely-contract-cancer-men.htmlhttp://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-2349455/Women-30s-40s-TWICE-likely-contract-cancer-men.html)

> Arthritis: What are the symptoms and who is likely to contract it?

[*compleatmother.com*](http://www.compleatmother.com/womens-health/arthritis/arthritis3.shtml)

**[Catch](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/catch?q=catch)** means

> contract (an illness) through infection or contagion:
>   *he served in Macedonia, where he caught malaria*

The principal difference is that *catch* suggests a transmittable infection, while *contract* can refer to a wider variety of diseases, including those that are not contagious.

Comment: +1; excellent distinction. "Contract" is more appropriate for non-communicable diseases.

Comment: As a native speaker, I can attest to how you can't contract a non-contagious disease. Catch and contract mean the same thing.

Comment: I'm a native speaker, and I'd second CopperKettle's confusion. Bib, can you add a concrete example of a non-contagious disease that we say is *contracted*? I wouldn't use the word for things like cancer or arthritis. Here are some relevant Word Reference forum threads that seem to support this: [develop a disease - contract a disease](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/develop-a-disease-contract-a-disease.1836454/), [suffer (from) a disease; contract a disease; develop a disease](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/suffer-from-a-disease-contract-a-disease-develop-a-disease.2407410/)

Comment: A quote from the second link: "An individual contracts a disease... typically by being exposed to something contagious; diseases with an infectious etiology are contracted (hepatitis, STDs, yellow fever etc.) In other words, you don’t contract a heart attack or a broken leg."

Comment: @sumelic Added examples of *contract* for non-infectious diseases. I am not suggesting that this is a medical distinction, only a common usage.

Comment: Eh, the examples seem to me as just using imprecise terminology, it feels wrong to "contract cancer".

Comment: @bjb568 This [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=contract+cancer&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccontract%20cancer%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccontract%20cancer%3B%2Cc1) seems to show thousands of uses of the phrase *contract cancer*. Again, not a scientific claim.

Comment: @bjb This is atypical, but interesting: *... medical-malpractice action arising out of her sister’s death from cancer contracted from a donated organ.* http://boards.medscape.com/forums/?128@@.2a7a7f2a!comment=1

Comment: @JimReynolds - this looks logical. The organ contained cancerous cells, and so the woman contracted cancer. It's the cancer 'contracted' out of the blue that looks illogical/imprecise in terms of terminology. But since it does occur in literature, it must look okay at least to a big section of native speakers.

Comment: @CopperKettle Thanks. Very generous of you to encourage participation and effort.

Answer (score 10):

**[contract](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/contract?q=contract)** 3 /kənˈtrakt/  [with object] **catch** or develop (a disease or infectious agent): *three people contracted a killer virus*

Use *contract* in formal or technical English.

Use *catch* in informal or plain English.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't so much a separate answer as a clarification to the correct answer provided by bib and to answer the comments about contracting a non-contagious disease.  I don't have the reputation yet to comment, so I'm putting it in an answer.

Many chronic conditions which should not strictly speaking be called a disease are, in fact, called diseases.  For example, heart disease is not something contracted from another carrier like a virus or bacteria, but is instead caused by the combination of factors of genetic predisposition, lifestyle, age, and chance.  Yet, one can **contract** heart disease.  One cannot, however, catch heart disease.

If you look in the earlier definition of contract you will see that it has two possible definitions: to **catch** or to **develop**.

Also, I think this problem is arising from a shift in the meaning of the word disease.  Two decades ago you might have seen **heart condition** rather than **heart disease**, but for many of us there is still an implied requirement that a **disease** be caused by something external, while a **condition** is caused by something genetic or by lifestyle choice.  Forgive me if this observation is too much of a tangent.

Comment: I am confused by your last paragraph, which seems to say that 20 years ago the term was, correctly, heart condition (genetic, lifestyle cause), but that now it has shifted, incorrectly, to heart disease (external cause).  Can you clarify?  +1 despite my confusion.

Comment: Absolutely!  What we are witnessing is a shift in the meaning of the word.  Those of us who grew up with the old meaning still apply it.  Since the meaning of the word has shifted, that means some people's understanding is no longer in sync with current usage.  I still **internally** apply a standard to the word usage that is becoming outdated.  It is a part of the natural process for word meaning or usage to shift, and it's kind of exciting to notice it in process.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to add a distinction that is perhaps not wholly semantic, but rather pragmatic - that *contract* has a stronger connotation than does *catch*, it **sounds** more like something serious.

I think that this probably stems from the register of the two - *contract* is more formal, so we tend to use it when talking about serious diseases. But an academic paper about a cold virus would still use the term *contract* - so it is not that you can't use the term when talking about minor illnesses. On the other hand, it sounds a bit strange to talk about catching HIV...

Personally, although some answers above prove that not everyone feels this way, I would **only** ever use either of the terms to refer to something contagious. Heart disease is something that develops, it is not contracted. A brief perusal of Google Scholar shows that this seems to be case - I cannot find a single paper about contracting heart disease, diabetes or cancer, but there are many about developing all of them. There are, however, many papers about contracting contagious diseases.

Answer (score 3):

First, here are the definitions:

> **Contract** *verb*
> 3 [with object] Catch or develop (a disease or infectious agent): *three people contracted a killer virus*
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contract)
>
> **Catch** *verb*
> 7 Contract (an illness) through infection or contagion: *he served in Macedonia, where he caught malaria*
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/catch)

As definitions, they are very close synonyms. **In popular usage, though, I'd venture to suggest that *contract* relates more to the (scientific / medical) cause of the disease whereas *catch* relates more to (non-medical) blame for its onset.**

Let's put it in the following form:

> He caught / contracted the disease from X.

With *caught*, X is commonly something like *his classmates* (someone who had symptoms of the disease) or *from being out in the rain* (a general condition that refers to correlation of the condition with the symptoms, and not to the biological vector or arguably even the immune function). These instances of X don't sound as natural with *contract*.

With *contracted*, X is commonly something like *(eating) infected shellfish* (a biological vector).

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between the two versions with to contract and to catch. The first one is Latin (con-trahere, basic meaning to draw) and academic, the second one is colloqial and simple plain English.

Answer (score 2):

The crux of the difference does seem to lie in register, with "catch" being a simple, monosyllabic verb as opposed to the more latinate "contract".

I came across a worthwhile [overview of the historical development of English](https://courses.nus.edu.sg/course/elltankw/history/standardisation.htm) and this schism between the academic register and the common register, for those who are interested.